# What is the probability that $5$ men won't sit next to each other in a row of $20$ chairs?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that none of $5$ men won't sit next to each other in a row of $20$ chairs if only these $5$ men sit?

I have tried to solve this question. I got the total ways to be $\dbinom{20}{5}=15504$ and I got the total ways to be $1365$. This would make the answer $\dfrac{455}{5168}$. I'm not too sure if this is the right answer since my counting method was tedious. So mainly, I'm looking for a more efficient and accurate way. Thanks!

Any solutions?

Comment: Try doing it like 1-{probability 5 men sits together}

Comment: @ItiShree This is incorrect, there can be less than 5 men sitting together

Comment: @Allan doesn't the question states "none of the 5 men"?

Comment: Yes but you're missing out probability that 4,3, or 2 men sit together

Comment: Ok in that case the person has to remove the cases of 4 ,  3 and 2 men sitting together from 1 as well. I thought the question is only asking for case where 5 men won't sit together.

Comment: I'm not too sure that way is much better than just directly counting it out. You need to be careful for over counts when you have 3 people sitting next to one another and stuff.

Comment: I got a different answer by complementary counting... :( It seems way off, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We decode empty chairs with $0$s and non-empty chairs with $1$s and consider binary strings of length $20$ with $15$ zeros and $5$ ones. Since no men are allowed to sit next to each other we are asking for words which do not contain a string $11$.
>
> The number of all binary strings of length $20$ with $15$ zeros is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{20}{15}=15504
> \end{align*}

In order to count the number of strings of length $20$ without having a substring $11$ we consider words
with no consecutive equal characters at all. These words are called Smirnov words or Carlitz words. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.)

> A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We replace occurrences of $0$ in a Smirnov word by one or more zeros since there are no restrictions to them. This corresponds to a substitution of

\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Since we want to look for strings of length $20$ with precisely $5$ ones, we mark them with $t$

\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow tz\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We obtain by substituting (2) and (3) in (1) a generating function A(z,t)
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z,t)&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}-\frac{tz}{1+tz}\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{1+tz}{1-z-tz^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> To obtain the number of words of length $20$ with $5$ ones we calculate with some help of Wolfram Alpha
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^{20}t^5]A(z,t)=4368
> \end{align*}
>   and conclude the probability that $5$ man won't sit next to each other in a row of $20$ chairs is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{4368}{15504}\simeq 0.2817
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to count the number of ways to construct a desirable arrangement than to outright count the number of arrangements.  This is a method called "constructive counting."

Start with the five men A, B, C, D, E sitting in a row and count the number of ways to arrange the chairs.  There are 6 places we can place the 15 chairs -- before A, between A and B, between B and C, etc.  To make sure that none of the men are sitting next to each other, we first place one chair between A and B, one between B and C, etc.  Then we have 11 chairs to distribute among 6 different places -- which is easily counted with the "stars and bars" or "balls and urns" method.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the number of ways to divide $n$ into $k$ parts is the number of ways to arrange $n$ identical dots and $k-1$ identical separator bars, which is $\frac{(n+k-1 )!}{n! (k-1)!} = {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$.

Once the $5$ men are seated in some order, the remaining 15 chairs need to be distributed into 6 places (4 places are between them and two are in the left and right ends).  The number of ways to do this is the number of ways to divide $15$ into 6 parts, which is ${15+5 \choose 5} = 15504$, which is the denominator.

In how many ways can we distribute $15$ chairs into 6 places so that there is at least one chair between each consecutive pair of men?  First we place one chair into each of these 4 places.  The remaining $11$ chairs need to be distributed among the $6$ places. This can be done in ${11+5 \choose 5} = 4368$ ways.  This is the numerator, and the probability in question is therefore $4368/15504 \approx 0.2817$.